# How can i write raw data?

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I'm testing some things and i keep getting the error "write() argument must be str, not HTTPResponse" Here's my code:

```
import requests
image="http://www.casperdenhaan.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Logo.jpg"
savefile=open("image.png","w+")
savefile.write(requests.get(image).raw)
savefile.close()
```

I can get the raw data, but I can't write it to a new file. Is there a way i could get around this problem?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: `savefile.write(requests.get(image).content)`

Comment: Yes, that works! I've tried and you need both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you call .raw on the response object it returns an HTTPResponse object. You need to call .content to get a bytes object.

   ```
   type(requests.get(image).raw)
   urllib3.response.HTTPResponse

   type(requests.get(image).content)
   bytes
   ```
2. You need to open the file in write binary mode:

   ```
   open("image.png","wb")
   ```
3. I suggest using a "with" block, this way you don't need to explicitly close the file. Here is a working version of the code:

   ```
   import requests
   url = "http://www.casperdenhaan.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Logo.jpg"
   with open('image.png', 'wb') as f:
       f.write(requests.get(url).content)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try this way of doing it

```
import requests
img_url = "http://www.casperdenhaan.nl/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Logo.jpg"
img = requests.get(img_url)
with open('image.png', 'wb') as save_file:

        save_file.write(img.raw)
```

This way you don't have to deal with closing the file. Also, the  `'wb'` opens the file in a writable binary mode.